# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: "ORA-01843: not a valid month"

Tags: c#, oracle, api

I connect to Oracle via C# when debugging, I get the following error:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: "ORA-01843: not a valid month".
I thought it was the route. Changing the way to get variables via the url didn't help.

Oracle procedure:

```
    PROCEDURE TestSelect(YEARp IN INT, MONTHp IN INT, pResult OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
        BEGIN
            OPEN pResult FOR
            SELECT SUM(LOAD_MATERIALS), REG_DATE
            FROM PRODUCTION 
            WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM REG_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(MONTHp, 'MM')) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM REG_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(YEARp, 'YYYY'))
            GROUP BY REG_DATE;
        END TestSelect;
```

C#:

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public List<Charts> GetCertainEmployees(int month, int year)
        {
            List<Charts> SelectPerem = new List<Charts>();
            string conString = "User Id=*; Password=*; Data Source=*";
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.BindByName = true;

                        cmd.CommandText = "PACKAGE_PRACTICE.TestSelect";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("YEARp", OracleDbType.Int32, month, ParameterDirection.Input);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("MONTHp", OracleDbType.Int32, year, ParameterDirection.Input);

                        var pResult = new OracleParameter("pResult", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pResult);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        var res = (OracleRefCursor)pResult.Value;
                        var reader = res.GetDataReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Charts s = new Charts();
                            s.LOAD_MATERIALS = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                            s.REG_DATE = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
                            SelectPerem.Add(s);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            return SelectPerem;
        }
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
while (reader.Read()) {
```

Comment: Converting a month/year integer value to date and then back again to integer is pointless. Use simply `WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM REG_DATE) = MONTHp AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM REG_DATE) = YEARp
         `

Comment: What is the data type of `REG_DATE`?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, DATE

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Variables are mixed up in these lines:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("YEARp", OracleDbType.Int32, month, ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Parameters.Add("MONTHp", OracleDbType.Int32, year, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

Be careful! Thank you all for your time and answers!